# Encrypt 16 digits into 32 alphanumeric characters

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm looking for a way to encrypt 16 digits into an alphanumeric string of 32 chars.

Is there a known encryption algorithm that can achieve that (preferably an asymmetric one)?

Comment: *"preferably an asymmetric one"* - No, asymmetric crypto at this length is most likely completely insecure. Let's assume that the ciphertext is Base64 encoded. That leaves 24 bytes to work with. RSA with a 192 bit modulus will be instantly broken. You could look into ECIES without the authentication tag (not advisable).

Answer (score 2):

It takes 54 bits (or 7 bytes) to encode a 16 digit number.

An alphanumeric string only gives you 62 symbols (a-z A-Z 0-9).  This is only enough to encode ~5 bits.  In a straightforward encoding 5*32 = 160 bits (or 20 bytes).

So your question reduces to:

Is there an encryption algorithm that can encrypt 7 bytes into no more than 20 bytes.  If you could use 2 more symbols in addition to `[:alnum:]` then you could use base64 encoding at expand that 20 bytes to 24 AND use a standard, well understood encoding.

Unfortunately this is not going to be simple:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem 2048
$ openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
$ echo -n ABCDEFG > plaintext.txt
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt
$ ls -l encrypted.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 john  staff  128 Jan 18 10:40 encrypted.txt
```

The resulting file is 128 bytes -- far too many for your requirements.

If you could use public-key encryption to share a symmetric key "out of band", then you could use symmetric encryption which would easily meet your space requirements.